# TF drift when use IMU on Cartographer

Tags: ros, slam, imu, lidar

I want to use my IMU MPU9250 on the robot to perform 2D SLAM using Google Cartographer and RPLIDAR A1. But when my robot moves, the transformation goes crazy. The map rotates randomly (I see it in RVIZ).

When I use the mapper without IMU it works fine.

This is not an IMU issue because rviz shows me the normal IMU conversion when I'm not running Cartographer.

What should I check in this case? Let me know if you need any information, config files, code, videos to diagnose the problem.